# django: How to remove bullet point when printing form errors

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views, django-errors

Okay so I have a form and then I want to print the errors, if any, when the user submits in the form. So in my template, I have the code

```
{% if form.errors %}
    {{ form.errors }}
{% endif %}
```

Now, the problem is, suppose the user forgets to put in the username, django will display this error message.

```
username
    - This field is required.
```

Except the "-" is a bullet.. How do I remove the bullet point and just make it inline with username? I tried to use CSS and make the display inline but that didn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Alternatily to CSS, you can iterate over errors like:

```
{% for field, error in form.errors.items %}
    {% if field != '__all__' %}{{ field }}{% endif %}
    {{ error | striptags }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Hm and what's __all__ in this case? and does strip tags basically just remove all other html and css tags on the variable?

Comment: '__all__' contains non-field errors like those you raise in Form.clean(). Striptags removes all tags, and you need it cause {{ error }} comes with some wrapping by default.

Comment: Note that this method will strip *all* tags, meaning that the error `<ul class="errorlist"><li>The two password fields didn’t match.</li></ul>` goes to the plain text `The two password fields didn’t match`, so there is no longer an HTML element to attach styling to.  If you want to keep styling, you'll have to add your own HTML wrapper in the template, like `<p class="errorlist">{{ error | striptags }}</p>`

Answer (score 13):

This isn't really a django question, it's css. But in any case, you need to apply `list-style: none` to the error list, ie.

```
.errorlist {
    list-style: none;
}
```

Comment: Hm, it didn't seem to work but i'll give the thumbs up though because I think it should work and the only reason it didn't is because there was a problem somewhere else in my code though. @I S's answer worked fine as well.